# Build Android for unsupported device

Tags: android, linux, custom-rom, lineageos

I want to build Android (in particular lineageOS) for an unsupported device that uses a Rocketchip 3399 processor. As far as I found out I need:

- device tree
- kernel
- vendor blobs

Is it somehow possible to build a version for the ARM64 architecture without needing the things mentioned above? Like some generic build for this architecture?

Also, we got an Android 9 image from the manufacturer that is working on the device. Is it maybe possible to extract the information mentioned above from this?

If not is there maybe a chance of building an image for a similar device that is likely to work on ours?

Note: Building for the emulator is already working on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can request the manufacture for the sources(device tree, kernal etc). Since android is open source, the manufacturer is legally obliged to provide you the source code of the rom(except proprietary blobs).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do the verndor proprietary blobs change from one Android build to another? How about the kernel tree, I would like to build LOS 19.1 for the Motorola GS5 Plus (codename Sanders) and the Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 (gts28vewifi). Thanks!

Comment: The vendor blobs usually work as long as the android versions are not too far apart.  For the kernel tree, it might be a good idea to apply the new security patches and rebase it. I'm not super sure about if it'll work without any modifications for the newer lineage os. Mostly because the newer clang versions throw too many errors when compiling old kernels. Another solution might be to build kernel separately and then add it during the rom build. Try building the kernel with the sources you have now and you'll get an idea about the potential problems.